# How can I duplicate the chapter heading on another page without calling \chapter again?

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters, memoir

I basically want to reprint the chapter heading with all the same formatting/spacing/etc and have it print onto the next odd page. I sort of hacked together the spacings and everything with vspace from memoir's layout information, but is there a "smarter" way I should be doing this? I don't want to trigger a new TOC entry or adjust the counter for the chapters.

This is the command I wrote to wrap all the formatting together. It also does not seem to perfectly mirror the spacing in the initial chapter printout either (the gap after the chapter name and title is larger in this, but I don't understand why).

**Major update** I don't know why I didn't see this earlier in the manual, but this creates the proper spacing and is an example straight from the manual (p. 86).

If there is an easier way still, happy to still hear it, but this seems to resolve all the issues without needing to hack things together.

```
\newcommand{\printPreLabStart}{%
{\clearforchapter
\insertchapterspace
\printchaptername\chapternamenum\printchapternum
\afterchapternum
\printchaptertitle{Pre-lab Questions}
\afterchaptertitle}
}
```

Comment: Not an expert on memoir, but with standard LaTeX I would use `\@makechapterhead`.  It **is** defined for memoir.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Seems that command isn't accessible to me? It just prints text of makechapterhead. But I updated with a new solution

Comment: @JM: Can you provide a more comprehensive minimal example?

Comment: @Werner I will see what I can mock up in a bit, yes. I debated if I should show one or not for this question

Comment: @JM To use `\@makechapterhead` you should do `\makeatletter
\@makechapterhead{Chapter title}
\makeatother`.